# Regarding Finding the Shortest Distance Picode

Tags: python, data-analysis

I have 2 columns of pin codes and distance of the other column Data Frame, I want to Find the Shortest Distance of Branch Pin for each Customer Pin, Can anyone help me out.

[image]

Comment: Do there are multiple distance for the pincode . e.g a1 = [121, 192, 12] , a2 = [121, 182, 11]  and you want to find the 11 as it is the shortest distance

Comment: Thanks @kd007 .Your answer makes sense to me.

Comment: @kd007 Yes, I want to find a1 = [ 12 ] and a2 = [ 11 ].